# Why does my Block not get loaded?

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

I don't know why my block does not get loaded. I already cleared the cache (incl var/cache). Can someone help me figure out what I missed? However, the `Here:` shows up!

here is my layout xml:
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/gpa/items.phtml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <gpa_adminhtml_gpa_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="gpa" template="gpa/items.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </gpa_adminhtml_gpa_index>
</layout>
```

items.phtml content:
    `Here: <?php echo $this->getItems() ?>`

block definition:

```
class Mymodulenamespace_Gpa_Block_Adminhtml_Gpa extends Mage_Core_Block_Template {
    public function getItems() {
        echo 'ABCDEF';
    }
}
```

here is my controller:

```
class Mymodulenamespace_Gpa_Adminhtml_GpaController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction() {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

I can see the output "Here:" so I know my Controller is being loaded correctly and the layout xml is also correct. 
But why isn't my Block getting instantiated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please change **Mage_Core_Block_Template** with **Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template** and instead of defining XML layout, try this:

```
class Mymodulenamespace_Gpa_Block_Adminhtml_Gpa extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template {
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->setTemplate('gpa/items.phtml');
        parent::_construct();
    }
    public function getItems() {
        echo 'ABCDEF';
    }
}
```